# reformatting a libsvm file to tab separated format in pandas or python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a libsvm format file with entries like

```
1.00000 id:0 1:50.44424 2:2.05040 3:0.00000 4:0.00000 5:0.00000 6:0.98826 7:1.00000 8:0.00000 9:0.50000 10:1.00000 11:1.00000 12:0.00000 13:4.00000 14:2.93121
11.0000 id:0 1:40.23844 2:2.39374 3:0.00000 4:0.00000 5:0.00000 6:0.92109 7:1.00000 8:0.00000 9:0.50000 10:0.44615 11:1.00000 12:0.00000 13:4.00000 14:5.80207
```

and I want to transform this data into this format extracting the values for each feature into a column.

```
1.0000  0  50.44424 2.05040 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.98826 1.00000 0.00000 0.50000 1.00000 1.00000 0.00000 4.00000 2.93121
11.0000  0 40.23844 2.39374 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.92109 1.00000 0.00000 0.50000 0.44615 1.00000 0.00000 4.00000 5.80207
```

I was trying to do using normal file reads in python as I was not sure we can this sort of manipulation inside pandas dataframe. But I am struggling to parse the values correctly. For example even when I try to extract the label using the code below.

```
writer = csv.writer( open( output_file, 'wf' ))
with open('train-en-us.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        label = line[0]
        print(f'{label}')
```

I get

```
1
1
```

not

```
1.0000 
11.0000
```

I also tried 
    line = map( lambda x: tuple( x.split( ":" )), line )
        print(f'{list(line)[0]}')

Is it better to do this manipulation in pandas or there is a quick way to do it python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need the built-in `csv` module, nothing fancy:

```
import csv

with open('input.txt') as fp_in:
    reader = csv.reader(fp_in, delimiter=' ')

    with open('output.txt', 'w') as fp_out:
        writer = csv.writer(fp_out, delimiter=' ')
        for row in reader:
            label = row[0]
            cols = [col.split(':')[1] for col in row[1:]]
            writer.writerow([label] + cols)
```